# How can I save a struct with pointers(what is pointed to aswell) to a file - C

Tags: c, file, struct, restore

Iam trying to create a program that can SAVE the information pointed to also in a file. So i'am able to load it and use it later.

Here is my struct two structs:

```
typedef struct{
    char name[11];
    char efternamn[11];
}person;

typedef struct{
    int numbofpersons;
    person * personList;
}personGOD;

personGOD controller;
int choice;
do
{
    printf("(1) to Initialize x amount of persons\n"
           "(3) to Save\n"
           "(5) Load controller\n");
    scanf("%d", &choice);
    switch (choice)
    {

    case 1  :
        InitializePersons(&controller);
        break;
    case 3  :
        SavePersonsToFile(&controller);
        break;

    case 5 :
        LoadController(&controller);
        break;
    }
}
while(flag);
```

Here is the functions Load,Save, Initialize:

```
void InitializePersons(personGOD* controller)
{
    int amount, i;
    printf("How many persons to be created");
    fscanf(stdin, "%d", &amount);

    controller->personList = (person*)calloc(amount, sizeof(person));

    for(i=0; i < amount; i++)
    {
        printf("Name: ");
        fscanf(stdin, "%s", controller->personList[i].name);

        printf("lastname: ");
        fscanf(stdin, "%s", controller->personList[i].efternamn); //eftername=lastname
    }
    controller->numbofpersons = amount; // update how many persons we current have
}

void SavePersonsToFile(personGOD* controller)
{

    FILE* fileptr;
    if((fileptr = fopen("C:\\Users\\x\\Desktop\\OpenStruct\\persons", "r+b"))== NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening file: %s\n", strerror( errno ));
        exit(0);
    }

    if(fwrite(controller, sizeof(personGOD), 1, fileptr)<1)
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", strerror( errno ));
    fclose(fileptr);

}

void LoadController(personGOD* controller)
{
    FILE* fileptr;
    if((fileptr = fopen("C:\\Users\\x\\Desktop\\OpenStruct\\persons", "r+b"))== NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening file: %s\n", strerror( errno ));
        exit(0);
    }
    if(fread(controller, sizeof(personGOD), 1, fileptr)<1){
                fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", strerror( errno ));
    }
    fclose(fileptr);
}
```

What will happen when i save->closeprogram->open->load is that numofpersons is correct and the personList will point to not allocated memory anymore and crash.

Having hard time googling how to accomplish this.

**How to save&restore pointed to data**

Comment: Yeah, it's not that simple.  A pointer is usually just a 64 (or 32) bit number internally that corresponds to a place in memory, so when you write a personGOD out it will just write the numbofpersons (in binary bytes), followed by your pointer 8 (or 4) bytes of binary data and likely with some structure padding thrown in between the two.  You'll need to manually encode and decode your data explicitly.

Comment: Google "serialization".

Comment: I'd suggest using some json (or xml if you prefer) library to write and read back your data, unless you absolutely require binary file firmat.

Answer (score 3):

You generally never want to write raw pointer data to files since if you re-run your program later (or on another machine, use another compiler etc.), there is no guarantee that the objects will have the same addresses.

So, you need to write the fields separately, since fwrite has no idea of what type of data you want to write. This is indicated by the first parameter of fwrite with type `const void*`.

An example (minus the error handling):

```
fwrite(&controller->numberofpersons, sizeof(controller->numberofpersons), 1, fileptr);
fwrite(controller->personList, sizeof(*controller->personList), controller->numberofpersons, fileptr);
```

For reading the file you use the same logic:

```
fread(&controller->numberofpersons, sizeof(controller->numberofpersons), 1, fileptr);
controller->personList = calloc(controller->numberofpersons, sizeof(*controller->personList);
fread(controller->personList, sizeof(*controller->personList), controller->numberofpersons, fileptr);
```

This solution have problems with endianness, so it's not completely portable, but that is another story.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot save memory pointers to a file and read it back. Memory is quite dynamic and you are guaranteed to get a memory violation using this method. In any modern OS this won't work. What you are doing is a crude solution for an inmemoryDB but for persistency you need to write the actual data and the @ load time, recreate the datastructures after reading(parsing) the data into memory.

Comment: Any recommendation where or what i can read how to manage this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It's better not to re-invent the wheel. There are many tools capable of serialization task. What to choose is up to you. Personally, I'd prefer SQLite as it is portable, flexible, relatively lightweight, has no dependencies and easily integrates into C source. Yet it implies re-writing your data as relational tables and using SQL which you may not like (want to) etc.